# 500 Internal Server Error after changing AllowOverride to All in Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

My Project is working fine in Blue host shared hosting and as well in my XAMPP localhost.

For testing we moved the files to a local ubuntu server. But .htaccess not working in this ubuntu server. 
Which means the files accesible with .php extention but 404 error when accesed without .php extention.

`http://172.31.0.55/project/contact.php` works, but
`http://172.31.0.55/project/contact` shows 404 error

This is the htaccess code I use.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /project/$1.php [L]
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?172.31.0.55/project/ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?172.31.0.55/project/.*$ [NC]


ErrorDocument 403 http://172.31.0.55/project/403-error
ErrorDocument 404 http://172.31.0.55/project/404-error
```

After some research I changed lines in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But now its showing 500 Internal server error when tried to access `http://172.31.0.55/project/`

Server version is `Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)`
Its a PHP Website

I can see following codes in http://172.31.0.55/ Apache default page

`The configuration layout for an Apache2 web server installation on Ubuntu systems is as follows:`

```
/etc/apache2/
|-- apache2.conf
|       `--  ports.conf
|-- mods-enabled
|       |-- *.load
|       `-- *.conf
|-- conf-enabled
|       `-- *.conf
|-- sites-enabled
|       `-- *.conf
```

I tried changing from ip address to localhost in htaccess. But not working

I checked for File permission its `rwx rwx r-x`

I made these changes referring https://askubuntu.com/questions/421233/enabling-htaccess-file-to-rewrite-path-not-working

Comment: check if rewrite_module is loaded or not using apachectl -l

Comment: That `Options All -Indexes` looks oddly positioned. In general if you had `AllowOverride none` it meant that `.htaccess` was not working and when you enabled it getting a 500 error means that there's probably an error in the `.htaccess` file. Check the  apache error log for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Apache prohibits using an .htaccess file to apply rewrite rules, so first you need to allow changes to the file. Open the default Apache configuration file using nano or your favorite text editor in this path */etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf*

`$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Inside that file, you will find a `<VirtualHost *:80>` block starting on the first line. Inside of that block, add the following new block so your configuration file looks like the following. Make sure that all blocks are properly indented.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

. . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and close the file. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

I followed these steps and my issue resolved.

Comment: I got error 404 and did the upper settings, what would be the issue?

Comment: @Duna It means mod_rewrite is not working as the user friendly url is not pointing to an actual file. It is caused due to: The mod_rewrite is not enabled or your htaccess file is not being processed.

Comment: What effect does editing the default config have on other virtual hosts?

Answer (score 2):

and also first

I had the same issue. After searching a lot I have found that @Doug Smythies's way perfectly work for me. Up vote.

So I go to the terminal and run the following code:

sudo a2enmod rewrite 
sudo service apache2 restart
And that's it. Hope this will help others.

<Directory /var/www/html/project1>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Require all granted

remove project 1 from your directory name and then solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: just sudo a2enmod rewrite works for me, tks